# Incorrect Results With Punctuation - ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I have a name field that is indexed using the `english` analyzer that contains part names (also tried the standard analyzer).

The problem I have is some of my titles contain punctuation, some do not. Also, some of my queries contain punctuation and some do not.

For example I have the title "CenterG 5.2 Drive Belt for model number 4425". My query could look like this: "Centerg 5.2 belt" and if it does, then my results display correctly with the "CenterG 5.2 Drive Belt for model number 4425" at the top.

However, if my query does not contain punctuation, the product does not display in the results. I have the same problem for titles that don't contain punctuation and queries that do. I'm not sure how this should be handled. I tried using the `standard` analyzer which I understand disregards punctuation, but that did not improve the results. They were roughly the same.

**So, when I search for "CenterG 5.2 Belt" or "centerg 52 belt", I want the product "CenterG 5.2 Drive belt for model number 4425" to display at the top of my results.**

Here is my mapping:

```
{:properties=>{:name=>{:type=>"text", :analyzer=>"english"}}
```

I have also tried leveraging an ngram analyzer which did not fix this problem.

Here is my query:

```
       {
            query: {
                bool: {
                    should: 
                       {
                            multi_match:{
                                fields: ["name"],
                                query: "#{query}"
                            }
                        }
                 }
              }

        }
```

Comment: So all what you want is to preserve your punctuation marks in your documents, so that when query contains them, then only they should come in result otherwise not? In this case, Please bold your expected O/P which you want which an detailed example.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I added an update. Thanks

Comment: wouldn't it be wrong to show results for `centerg 52 belt"`, as title contained `5.2`  not `52` which is very different ?

Comment: For most purposes yes but the data I am dealing with sucks so I am trying to ultimately ignore the `.`. I have cases where some model numbers may not contain a `.` but the query might so that gives strange results also. I have a lot of cases where the model number might be longer such as `PFT11473.1` and I need `PFT114731` to match.

Comment: First part is completed, I would write detailed answer soon, I am trying the solution on es 7.x, which version u use

Comment: 7.3. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199047/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-cannon-moyer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to achieve with just 1 field and 1 analyzer. first part of your example is easy to achieve if you just use a custom analyzer which removes all the dots `.` with empty space, both at index time and query time.

But in your comment, you mentioned that you want to search document containing `PFT11473.1` with search query `PFT11473`, for which you need to create another analyzer which would replace `.` with space , so that 2 tokens are generated `PFT11473` and `1` and anyone would be searchable.

I created 2 fields for storing your `title` field using 2 different analyzers which serves both the use-cases you mentioned.

Below is the index mapping:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "replace_dots"
                    ]
                },
                "space_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "replace_dots_space"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "replace_dots": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        ". =>"
                    ]
                },
                "replace_dots_space": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        ". => \\u0020"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "type": "text"
            },
            "title_space": {
                "analyzer": "space_analyzer",
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I indexed one example doc:

```
{
  "title" : "PFT11473.1",
  "title_space": "PFT11473.1"
}
```

And final search query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "PFT11473.1",
            "fields": [
                "title",
                "title_space"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```